# Swipe refresh for view in React native

Tags: react-native, swiperefreshlayout

I have following layout structure

```
<View>
      <HeaderView/>
      <FlatList/>
<View/>
```

I want to implement swipe refresh on the parent View and not FlatList. I can't wrap the whole     View using Scrollview as I need only FlatList to be scrollable and not the HeaderView.

I have tried to put Refreshcontrol for FlatList but in that case the loading icon does not emerges from the top of the parent view but from the top of FlatList.

What are the ways to do it?

Answer (score 2):

The `FlatList` Component has a `ListHeaderComponent` property that you can use to add the header to the `FlatList` rather than adding it above it like so:

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}>
  <FlatList
    ListHeaderComponent={<HeaderView />}
    refreshControl={
      <RefreshControl
        refreshing={this.state.refreshig}
        onRefresh={this.onRefresh}
      />
    }
  />
</View>
```

For a running example, you can check this [snack](https://snack.expo.io/@fayeed/vengeful-marshmallows).